# Proving homotopic equivalence between $^m$ and $R^{m+1}-\{0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

I'm studying differential forms, integration on surfaces, and these concepts are defined in exercises. The first exercise defines this concept:

> Let $M$ be a surface $C^{\infty}$. Two closed forms $\alpha, \beta$ of
>   degree $r$ and $C^{\infty}$ are cohomologous when $\alpha-\beta$ is
>   exact. Then the equivalence class $[\alpha]$ constitutes the vector
>   space $H^r(M)$, called the cohomology group of degree $r$ in the
>   surface $M$. Every map $f:M\to N$, $C^{\infty}$, induces the linear
>   transformation $f^*:H^r(N)\to H^r(M)$ such that $(g\circ f)^* = f^*
>  \circ g^*$, defined by $f^*[\alpha] = [f^*\alpha]$

Now, the exercise I'm supposed to answer is this one, which defines some concepts too:

> We say that two surfaces $M, N$, $C^{\infty}$, have the same type of
>   homotopy when there are maps $f:M\to N$ and $g:N\to M$, $C^{\infty}$,
>   such that $g\circ f $ and $f\circ g$ are maps homotopics to the
>   correspondent identities. In this case, $f$ is called a homotopic
>   equivalence and $g$ its homotopic inverse. Prove that, in this case,
>   $f^*:H^k(N)\to H^k(M)$ and $g^*:H^k(M)\to H^k(N)$ are, for $k=0,1,
>  \cdots$ isomorphisms. Show that the inclusion $i: S^m\to
>  \mathbb{R}^{m+1}-\{0\}$ and the radial projection $p:
>  \mathbb{R}^{m+1}-\{0\}\to S^m$ (defined by $p(x) = x/|x|$) are
>   homotopic equivalences between $S^m$ and $R^{m+1}-\{0\}$. Conclude
>   that the cohomology groups $H^k(S^m)$ and
>   $H^k(\mathbb{R}^{m+1}-\{0\})$ are isomorph for $k=0,1, \cdots$

I don't have much theory to solve this, I'm lost. For example, I know that $p$ maps from $\mathbb{R}^{m+1}-\{0\}$ to $S^m$. I know that $i
\circ p$ is the identity on $\mathbb{R}^{m+1}-\{0\}$, and I can also make the 'reverse' identity. Is it trivial that these two are identities one of another? How to show that these composites are homotopic to the identity? How to show that $f^*$ and $g^*$ are isomorphisms?

I think this is a classical result and there are much content that I can read about, but I couldn t find anything specific to the sphere and $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, You are wrong, $i\circ p$ is not the identiy on $\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}$.

Secondly, A little bit of definitions and facts that you can find in any book of differential forms.

Let $f,g; M\rightarrow N$ be $C^\infty$ maps between manifolds. We say that **$f$ is homotopic to $g$ or $f \sim g$** if there is a $C^\infty$ map $F : M \times [0,1] \rightarrow N$ such that $F(x,0) = f(x)$ and $F(x,1) = g(x)$ for any $x \in M$. Such a map $F$ is called a **homotpy** between $f$ and $g$.

A main relation between the notion of homotopy and the maps induced in cohomology is the following remark

> If $f \sim g$  then $f^* = g^* : H^*(N) \rightarrow H^*(M)$.

Now, **we say that $f: M \rightarrow N$ is a homotopy equivalence with homotpy inverse $g: N \rightarrow M$ if there are homotpies**

$$ g \circ f \sim id_M$$ and 
$$ f \circ g \sim id_N$$

> Note that if $f$ is a homotpy equivalence with homotpy inverse $g$, by the above Remark we get in cohomology the equalities

$$f^*\circ g^* = (g \circ f)^* = (id_M)^* = id_{H^*(M)}$$

and

$$g^*\circ f^* = (f \circ g)^* = (id_N)^* = id_{H^*(N)}$$

This means, ***$f^*$ and $g^*$ are isomorphisms in Cohomology***

Finally, going back to your original concern. where $i:S^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m+1}-\{0\}$ is the inclusion and $p: \mathbb{R}^{m+1}-\{0\} \rightarrow S^m$ is the radial projection. Notice

$$ p \circ i (x) = x = id_{S^m};$$

Therefore $(p \circ i)^* = id_{H^*(S^m)}$.  On the other hand,

$$ i\circ p (x) = x/|x|$$

In this case, the composite is not the identiy on $\mathbb{R}^{m+1}-\{0\}$ but *it is homotopic to $id_{\mathbb{R}^{m+1}-\{0\}}$*

Question: Can you think on a map $F: \mathbb{R}^{m+1}-\{0\} \times [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m+1}-\{0\}$ such that $F(x,0) = x$ and $F(x,1) = x/|x|$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^{m+1}-\{0\}$? Picturing everything in $\mathbb{R}^3$ would be very useful.

That is, $F$ is a homotpy between $i \circ p$ and $id_{\mathbb{R}^{m+1}-\{0\}}$ and conclude that $i$ is a homotpy equivalence with homotpy inverse $p$.

Comment: I came up with $F(x,t) = x/(|x|+(1-t)(1-|x|))$, it does what you asked. Is it right?

Comment: The problem with your suggestion is that the denominator might vanish. You can define the homotopy as $F(x,t)= tx+(1-t)x/|x|$, that is, the line segment joining x and x/|x|.

Comment: Ok, that works. Now what should I do to conclude that $i$ is a homotopy equivalence with inverse $p$ exactly? How that proves isomorphisms between cohomology groups?

Comment: If you try to understand what I expose in my answer at least, you can find the solutions to your questions there.

Comment: Ok. First, by your remark, since $f^* = g^*$, then I didn't get why $f^*\circ g^*$ should be equal to $(g\circ f)^*$

Comment: By your definition, for $i$ to be a homotopy equivalence with homotopy inverse $p$, they should be inverses of each other They're not. They're almost, because $i\circ p$ is homotopic to the identity. But the definition say they must be equal... Maybe I'm supposed to compose something. I'm really trying

Comment: $(g \circ f)^* = f^* \circ g^*$ is easily proved from the definition of the maps. It means, $f^*(\alpha) = \alpha \circ f$.  For the second concern, being inverses IS NOT THE SAME that being homopy inverses; however, if the composite $(i \circ p)$ is HOMOTOPIC to the identity (as maps between manifolds) , they become EQUAL as maps of cohomology rings, namely $(i \circ p)^* = id_{H^*(\mathbb{R}^{m+1}-\{0\}}$.

Comment: You can review all these facts, for instance, from the Lee's book: Introduction to Smooth manifolds. In chapter 11 he deals with deRham cohomology and provides detailed proofs of the facts that your problem needs to be solved.